# Have puppet ensure a service is running only when not in a maintenance mode

Tags: puppet

I have a basic service check in a puppet manifest I want running most of the time with just

```
service{ $service_name :
    ensure => "running",
    enable => "true",
}
```

The thing is there are periods of maintenance I would like to ensure puppet doesn't come along and try to start it back up.

I was thinking creating a file "no_service_start" in a specified path and do a 'creates' check like you could do with a guard for exec but it doesn't look like that's available for the service type.

My next thought was to have the actual service init script do the check for this file itself and just die early if that guard file exists.

While this works in that it prevents a service from starting it manifests itself as a big red error in puppet (as expected).  Given the service not starting is a desired outcome if that file is in place I'd rather not have an error message present and have to spend time thinking about if it's "legit" or not.

Is there a more "puppet" way this should be implemented though?

Answer (score 2):

Define a fact for when maintenance is happening.

Then put the service definition in an if block based off that fact.

```
if !maintenance
{
    service{ $service_name :
       ensure => "running",
       enable => "true",
    }
}
```

Then when puppet compiles the catalog if maintenance == true the service will not be managed and stay in whatever state it currently happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

As xiankai said, you can do this on the puppetmaster. If you have a script that returns `running` or `stopped` as a string, depending on the current time or anything, you can write something like:

```
service{ $service_name :
    ensure => generate('/usr/local/bin/maintenanceScript.sh');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really like this answer, but to work around puppet spitting out errors when bailing b/c of a guard file is to have to init script that's doing that check bail with an exit code as 0.

Answer (score -1):

How about putting the check outside? You could do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20552751/1097483, except with your service check inside the if loop.